# How does composition in the category Rel work if not all relations are transitive?

Tags: category-theory, relations

My understanding of categories is that composition is always possible: if you have an arrow *f* from A to B and an arrow *g* from B to C, then you also have a third arrow from A to C that represents the composition of *f* and *g*. However, I'm confused about what this means in the category **Rel** if some of the relations are not transitive. If *f* represents a non-transitive relation between A and B, and *g* represents a non-transitive relation between B and C, then the composition of these relations might include pairs of elements that aren't actually related. What am I misunderstanding here?

**Edit:** Is the composition just the null set?

**Edit 2:** I see where I went wrong here: I was treating the arrows of **Rel** as itself a relation on the set of objects in the category, in which case composition would make it into a transitive relation. But each arrow represents a different relation, and transitivity is a property of a *single* relation, not a collection of them. Whoops. (Also, now I realize why it makes no sense to speak of a heterogenous relation being transitive.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by a transitive relation between two sets. The composition is a new relation, which is different from the previous relations (in general); in particular, even if $A = B = C$, it may relate new pairs of elements that neither the original relations relate.

One way to connect this to transitivity is that a relation $R$ on a set $X$ is transitive iff the composition $R \circ R$ is contained in $R$ (in the sense of subset containment). Moreover we can calculate the transitive closure of $R$ (the smallest transitive relation containing $R$) by taking the union over all composites $\bigcup_{n \ge 1} R^{\circ n}$.

Comment: Yeah, I think my mistake was a failure to understand that the concept of transitivity is specifically a property of relations on individual sets, not relations between sets.

Comment: @Matt: well, composition still makes sense and is generally nontrivial even for non-transitive relations on an individual set.

Comment: Right, I understand that composition makes sense... it just hadn't clicked that transitivity as a concept is understood in the context of homogenous relations, whereas arrows between objects in Rel are heterogeneous relations. I think I get it now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, I see where I went wrong here: I was treating the category of Rel as itself a relation on the set of objects in the category, in which case composition would make it into a transitive relation. But each arrow is a separate relation, and transitivity is a property of a single relation, not a collection of them. Whoops.